# Longitudinal data analysis with relationships information

Tags: mixed-model, panel-data, multilevel-analysis, clinical-trials

I am part of a study where we are trying to understand the effect of social interaction on weight loss. The idea is to have two sets of Groups. In Group 1 there are group of people joining as a family or related individuals(friends etc.), who take part in weight loss program and asked to socially interact and take part in activities after the sessions as well. Then there is second similar group of people but they aren't encouraged to interact with each other after the session. We want investigate the impact of weight changes of family and friends on an individual's weight change, e.g. larger weight loss of family/friends may lead to larger weight loss of an individual.

So I have data which is longitudinal in nature. For each individual there is information available of their weight for 10 different sessions and which group did they belong to. Now analyzing this was doable using Linear Mixed Models and I have seen plenty of examples on the net.

But there is another dataset where for each individual, I have information on which ID(person) is related to which person(this person's weight change info is also available). So my scenario is as such that not only I need to find if people belonging to group 1 overall weight loss(or gain) was significant and it wasn't for group 2, but I need to make use of the relationship info as well.

Neither I am able to find any such use case where such thing was done or able to figure out how to do it. My supervisor is suggesting to use Linear Mixed Models here but I am not able to figure out how to frame the data in such a way that I can use such a model and then interpret it.

The datasets are in this format:
The firt dataset df1:
{'id', 'group', 'age', 'gender', 'Session_1', 'Session_2', 'Session_3', 'Session_4', 'Session_5', 'Session_6', 'Session_7', 'Session_8', 'Session_9', 'Session_10'}

A sample dataset:
df1:

```
'id', 'group', 'age', 'gender', 'Session_1', 'Session_2', 'Session_3', 'Session_4', 'Session_5', 'Session_6', 'Session_7', 'Session_8', 'Session_9', 'Session_10'
101, GroupA, 45, M, 76, 75, 76, 78, 75, 75, 74, 74, 73, 73
102, GroupA, 42, F, 56, 57, 56, 58, 55, 55, 54, 53, 55, 54
103, GroupA, 72, M, 80, 81, 80, 82, 79, 79, 78, 77, 79, 78
104, GroupA, 41, F, 60, 61, 60, 62, 59, 59, 58, 57, 59, 58
105, GroupB, 44, M, 76, 75, 76, 78, 75, 75, 74, 74, 73, 73
106, GroupB, 41, F, 56, 57, 56, 58, 55, 55, 54, 53, 55, 54
... and so on
```

And df2:
{'id', 'id_relation', 'household', 'closefriend', 'acquint', 'closerel', 'extendfam', 'spouse_blood', 'spouse_notblood', 'group'}.

Sample dataset:

```
'id', 'id_relation', 'household', 'closefriend', 'acquint', 'closerel', 'extendfam', 'spouse_blood', 'spouse_notblood', 'group'
101, 102, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, GroupA
101, 103, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, GroupA
102, 101, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, GroupA
102, 103, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, GroupA
103, 101, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, GroupA
103, 102, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, GroupA
104, 105, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, GroupB
104, 106, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, GroupB
105, 104, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, GroupB
105, 106, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, GroupB
106, 104, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, GroupB
106, 105, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, GroupB
... and so on
```

The other column here give you information about what is the relation of person in 'id' with person in 'id_relation'. I am thinking if just the relation info is enough and not the type of relationship. And just to be clear there are different sets of related people here, not just one single group.

I can merge the dataset and convert the df1 from wide form to long form, but then do what? How to model my dataset and what am I building the model on? What's the formula?

weight ~ ...+...+...?

Moreover how would I determine that was there overall weight loss or weight gain? Can using the mean/median value is enough for all sessions and then seeing the trendline?

Any kind of help, or link to code or study or methodology is appreciated.

Comment: As my initial research, this thing is a combination of longitudinal data analysis and social network analysis. Now I have searched a lot and have not found a clear solution or guide or anything on this till now.